# NLSSORT Oracle to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Trying to convert the following code from Oracle to SQL Server 2008:

```
order by NLSSORT(name, 'NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN')
```

I know `NLSSORT` is not a function in SQL Server, so how would I go about this?

Comment: The closest equivalent should be `ORDER BY name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`, as (per my understanding) `NLS_SORT=WEST_EUROPEAN` will perform a case-sensitive, accent-sensitive sort. (Oracle and SQL Server probably don't use the exact same data for sorting, though, so this can't be guaranteed to always produce the same results for all possible inputs.) This has some consequences for performance, though -- usually you would not vary the collation on the fly, but define the column with the correct collation initially in the table.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen, thought COLLATE might help!